# Помогите проверить расстановку знаков препинания в примере с цитатой?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Пример из фильма.

Курсант милиции рассуждает (цитата): "Избив одинокого молодого человека, его не прячут, какой смысл? - его тащат и кладут на рельсы".

(Сколько ошибок?)

Answer (score 2):

Оформление нормальное, добавлю  только комментарии.

1) Это БСП со значением противопоставления, поэтому ставится тире.

2)Вставка, обособленная тире, может иметь вопросительный знак, но такая ставка не должна находится на месте, где имеются знаки препинания (запятая или тире).

3) Деепричастный оборот не применяется в безличных предложениях, а здесь неопределенно-личное предложение, то есть неопределенный производитель действия всё-таки имеется.

Answer (score 1):

"Сколько" - ну это смотря как считать...
Вам только прямую речь героя проверять - или само оформление цитаты?
В оформлении цитаты я ошибок не вижу, если считать, что "какой смысл" относится к самой цитате (а не разбивает её как авторские слова).

А вот что до пунктуации в прямой речи, то тут сложно. Без вопросительного знака тут никак не обойтись, но внутри предложения в тексте вопросительный никакими правилами не предусмотрен - за исключением тех, которые стоят непосредственно перед закрывающими кавычкой или скобкой, в крайнем случае - перед закрывающем же парным тире (не совсем по правилам, но иногда применяется от безвыходности). Так что тут надо прин0имать мерs решительные. 
Так что, если искать беспроигрышный вариант, то я бы ввел скобки:

***Избив одинокого молодого человека, его не прячут (какой смысл?) - его тащат и кладут на рельсы***.

Тут можно спорить по части грамматики - о допустимости деепричастного оборота в такой конструкции, но современная трактовка этого правила, судя по всему, вполне такое допускает. И еще про запятую после скобки, но, насколько понимаю, и тут все чисто, запятая не требуется, её "поглотило" тире, а других мотивов для запятой не наблюдается.